# reinterpret_cast to know the type of the event at compilation time

Tags: c++, templates, optimization

I have an application based on events.
The issue is that I have a lot of different types of events and some classes listen a lot.

Currently, when I want to receive an event, I create a function taking the type of message as a parameter and I subscribe to it.
I would like to have a single function which receives all the events and which then calls the functions to process the event.
This is mainly to have a clearer view of my classes.
Of course, I would like to have the lowest possible cost, if not none.

I have found a way to do this which I think is at no additional cost since it should be handled at compile time.

I would like a confirmation that this is the case
and I'm wondering if this is a good practice or something that might cause me problems.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

enum class Type {
    Test, Test2
};

struct Test {
    vector<int>::iterator b;
    vector<int>::iterator e;
};

struct Test2 {
    int a = 0;
};

template<Type type>
void test(uintptr_t k) {
    if constexpr(type == Type::Test) {
        auto p = reinterpret_cast<Test*>(k);
        for (auto i = p->b; i != p->e; ++i) cout << *i << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    } else if constexpr(type == Type::Test2) {
        auto p = reinterpret_cast<Test2*>(k);
        cout << p->a << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    Test2 v{10};
    auto a = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&v);
    std::function<void(uintptr_t)> f_display = test<Type::Test2>;
    f_display(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you need to explicitly provide the test type, you might as well just have a bunch of `test` overloads, each with one of the `Type::Test` types.

Comment: Where is `v2` declared? Or was that supposed to be `v`?

Comment: `std::variant<Test*, Test2*>`?

Comment: The code as posted doesn't compile.  There is no `v2`, and `v` isn't a pointer.  I guess you mean `&v2` and you want the variable to be called `v2`?

Comment: what's the point of writing the code this way instead of using overloaded functions or template specializations? You can make it so `test<Test2>` works and you don't need the `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: I corrected the code, there was a typo.
My main goal was to have only one registered function to receive all the events.
I got the answers on what to do below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have one event queue that handles different kinds of events.  I get it, you can see this kind of thing with C# objects that have a bajillion customization hooks with different arguments; they have one subscription system for all of them, and cast to make sure that the types agree.

If you want a central bottleneck, I'd do it so you keep type safety as long as possible.

```
struct broadcaster {
  using callback = std::function<void(uintptr_t)>;
  using listener = std::weak_ptr<callback>;
  std::unordered_map<
    std::type_index,
    std::vector<listener>
 > listeners;

  template<class T, class F>
  std::shared_ptr<void> install_callback( F&& f ) {
    std::type_index index(typeid(T));
    auto cb = std::make_shared<callback>([f=std::forward<F>(f)](std::uintptr_t p){
      f( *reinterpret_cast<T*>(p) );
    });
    listeners[index].push_back( cb );
    return cb;
  }
  template<class T>
  std::size_t broadcast( T t ) {
    std::type_index index(typeid(T));
    auto it = listeners.find(index);
    if (it == listeners.end()) return 0;
    // remove uninstalled callbacks
    it->second.erase(
      std::remove_if(
        it->second.begin(), it->second.end(),
        [](auto&&wcb){return wcb.expired();}
      ),
      it->second.end()
    );
    // copy vector of callbacks for reentrancy purposes
    auto tmp = listeners.second;
    std::size_t retval = 0;
    for (auto&& wcb : tmp) {
      if (auto cb = wcb.lock()) {
        (*cb)( reintepret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(std::addressof(t)) );
        ++retval;
      }
    }
    return retval;
  }
};
```

I think that does it.

You `b.install_callback<Type>( some_function_taking_type )` and get back a `std::shared_ptr<void>`.  So long as the shared ptr remains valid, you are subscribed to the broadcaster.

Someone can send messages via `b.broadcast<Type>( t )`, which invokes every callback registered to `Type` that hasn't expired.  It also cleans out of the map any callbacks on that type that expired before the call to `broadcast`.

This might be too much for you, however.

The overhead here is a hash table lookup when you make a broadcast, then you have to walk over a vector and do some atomic operations to see if the callbacks are registered on a per-callback basis.

The actual callback has 1 layer of type erasure (assuming the installer used a naked lambda, not one already wrapped in a std function).

Type unsafety is isolated to this `broadcaster` class; inputs and outputs to this class's methods are type safe.

The number of types of stuff broadcast is an open set.  The callback and the broadcaster have to agree.

Probably a "prune" method that cleans up dangling weak ptrs that aren't being interacted with is worthwhile.

I used my shared ptr "token" approach to handle unregistering callbacks here.  Basically, the callback installer is responsible to keep the shared ptr around so long as the callback is valid.  This lets you have a class install a listener and just store a single shared ptr, or even a vector of them, and let RAII clean them up at destruction time.  (I find dangling callbacks to be a pain).

If the broadcaster dies first, no problem.  If the listener dies first, no problem.  The only possible problem is if while the listener is dieing and hasn't cleared the callback token the broadcaster broadcasts, and the listener isn't in a suitable state to listen.  That can be fixed by explicitly clearing the token in the listener when they no longer want to listen (say, at the first step in the destructor, or ensuring the token store is the first member, or whatever).

The above code has not been compiled, just written.  It probably contains tpyos.

Comment: Thanks, is the shared_ptr really necessary?

Comment: @antho when subscribing to a callback mechanism, how do you unregister?  If it is longer than a single function call, I find RAII is very useful to keep deregistration sane.

Comment: I use a unique id that is returned at subscription time.
When the object doesn't want to be subscribed anymore, it asks to be deleted from the event with its id.

My callback is wrapped in a class with the id to find it quickly in a vector.

Comment: @antho Sure; not RAII (so requires writing code to unregister, instead of just using a token lifetime), and relies on listeners not outliving the broadcaster (or knowing the lifetime of the broadcaster), but that approach works.  The shared ptr stuff is just to avoid having to write unregistration code, and handle "unregistered while iterating through callbacks" smoothly.

Comment: In reality, I use RAII but probably less clean than you.
In the shredder, I remove all the events to which the object is subscribed.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going the long way around with an enum to switch on, I would use a basic overload set that already provides the dispatching functionality, and add only the casting part on top:

```cpp
void test_impl(Test *p) {
    for (auto i = p->b; i != p->e; ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void test_impl(Test2 *p) {
    std::cout << p->a << '\n';
}

template <class Type>
auto test(uintptr_t const k) {
    return test_impl(reinterpret_cast<Type *>(k));
};
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jew7zX9pq7C0Ohai)

Comment: Why are you using a variable template and a lambda here, when a simple template function would be adequate?

Comment: @NicolBolas why, indeed. I started with a function template returning a lambda, then though I would be clever and use a variable to match OP's syntax. Somehow I didn't think of a simple function template ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯